# How can I add an instance attribute in subclass?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Student(Person):

    def register(self, school):
        pass
    def payfee(self, money):
        pass
    def chooseClassAndGrand(self, obj):
        pass

class Teacher(Person):
    pass
```

I want to add a `class` instance property to the Student class, how to do with that in the Student class code, if I do not want to rewrite the `__init__()` method?

Comment: You don't need to rewrite init. You call the super class' init in your init, and then declare your instance variable.

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword and will throw errors. You need to have a different name for the property

Comment: @Ronnie yeah, I use `classAndGrade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to rewrite `__init__`. Assuming you want `Person`'s `__init__` functionality to be invoked when creating an instance of `Student`, you may use the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) keyword inside the `__init__` function of `Student`:

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # python3.0+
        self.classAndGrade = ...

    ...
```

If you're on python < 3.0, you can use

```
super(Person, self).__init__()
```

This is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: My `Person` class is Classic class, can not use the `super()`, it will report ·`TypeError: must be type, not classobj` error

Answer (score 0):

Do add to COLDSPEED, you can also use the below to add attributes:

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, classAndGrade):
        Person.__init__(self, name)
        self.classAndGrade = classAndGrade

    ...
```